# How can i show language switcher in both the header and the footer?

Tags: magento2, blocks

How can i show language switcher in both the header and the footer, but with a different template than in the header? I would like to have another phtml file, where I can customize it...

Comment: is this a very stupid question or a very hard one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. I have a `footer` block that has a template file called `footer.phtml`. In that file I added this code:

```
<div class="container">
    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Store\Block\Switcher")->setTemplate("Magento_Store::switch/languages_footer.phtml")->toHtml() ?>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the solution tho, but your point is valid, I will edit my answer to reflect this.

Comment: You can mark this as your accepted answer after few hours. I would remove my  above comment.